# How to refer to a cell in data grid view using its index in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a purchase bill form in which the sold items must appear with their elements one of that element is the **unit** each time I will save the bill in the database each rows of the data grid view must check the **unit text** to make decisions on some conditions ... so how to refer to that cell in a condition where its index is 2
I tried to write it like this but it doesn't give any sense

```
if(pBilldgv.Rows.IndexOf(Cell[2]))
```

can any one give the syntax for referring to the cell in the data grid view .. regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple

```
if ( pBilldgv.Rows[index of your row].Cells[index of your cell or 2].Value.ToString() )
    // Do what ever you want to do.
```

The index cell is the column index or in another way the intersection of a row and a column will give you a cell.

Comment: and if I want to a cell in a query such as  
 cmd = new SqlCommand("select pack,tab,pill,piece from item where itmTrdName='" + pBillItemNametxt.Text + "' or itmBar='" + pBillItemBartxt.Text + "'", cn);
I want to use the sell content in a query instead of pBillItemNametxt.Text a textBox content

Comment: You want to use the cell content in a query?

Comment: should I insert it in a variable of type string then use it in my query or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Well if you are willing to retrieve all or some records from the database which have the same value as the the selected cell then you can use it like the way you used the textBox content of course you can put the cell value on a variable or use it like you see in the answer it depend on you taste but a variable would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the selected row in gridview

```
pBilldgv.SelectedRows[*IndexofRow*].Cells[*IndexofCell*].Value.ToString()
```

and you could do this:

```
//Depends on your Data Type
string sampleString = pBilldgv.SelectedRows[*IndexofRow*].Cells[*IndexofCell*].Value.ToString()

if(sampleString) {
   //Do stuff
}
```